# Resizing FancyBox modal when new data dynamically added

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, modal-dialog

I have a form on the following page:

http://mmicet.yazminmedia.com/qseries

(Click the "Keep me updated on the Q" button at the bottom.)

It's a form that uses frmValidator: http://www.javascript-coder.com/. It's basically the same form I'm using successfully on the contact page.

I read on the FancyBox API page that there is a resize function that would resize the modal when new data is added. However, the modal isn't resizing. Instead, my form is getting pushed down and the bottom portion is getting pushed down out of view. (The behavior can be duplicated by simply submitting the form without entering any information in it.)

These are the options I setup for the modal:

```
$("#qs_button").fancybox({
    'titleShow'     : false,
    'scrolling'     : 'no',
    'autoDimensions'    : false,
    'autoScale'     : false,
    'width'         : 600,
    'height'        : 870,
    'showCloseButton': true,
    'onClosed'      : function() {
        $("#login_error").hide();
    }       
});
```

I'm firing the resize function on submit of form:

```
$("#qseries_form").bind("submit", function() {

    $.fancybox.resize();

    $.ajax({
        type        : "POST",
        cache       : false,
        url     : "/qseries.php",
        data        : $(this).serializeArray(),
        success: function(data) {
            $.fancybox(data);
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

Anyone have any ideas why the resize isn't working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess, but shouldn't you resize the Fancybox *after* the data's been put there? Something like:

```
$("#qseries_form").bind("submit", function() {

    $.ajax({
        type        : "POST",
        cache       : false,
        url     : "/qseries.php",
        data        : $(this).serializeArray(),
        success: function(data) {

            $.fancybox(data);

            // resize after data's updated...
            $.fancybox.resize();
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

Hopefully I'm not completely off the mark here!

Answer (score 0):

Just try with this,
Because this worked in one of my recent project where i have to increase/decrease window size on click of radio button.

$('#fancybox-content').css('height','253px');